# sum value of a 3rd row and divide rows accordingly

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file as below with n number of rows, I want to total it's sum(based on 3rd column) and distribute rows accordingly in 3 different files(based on sum of each)

For example- if we sum all the 3rd column values it's total is coming as 516 and if we divide it by 3 it is 172.

So i want to add a rows to a file so it doesn't exceed 172 mark, same with the 2nd file and rest all rows should move to the third file.

Input file

```
a aa 10
b ab 15
c ac 17
a dy 30
y ae 12
a dl 34
a fk 45
l ah 56
o aj 76 
l ai 12 
q al 09
d pl 34
e ik 30
f ll 10
g dl 15 
h fr 17
i dd 23
j we 27
k rt 12
l yt 13
m tt 19
```

expected output

```
file1(total -163)


a   aa  10
b   ab  15
c   ac  17
a   dy  30
y   ae  12
a   dl  34
a   fk  45
```

file2 (total-153)

```
l   ah  56
o   aj  76
l   ai  12
q   al  9
```

file3 (total - 200)

```
d   pl  34
e   ik  30
f   ll  10
g   dl  15
h   fr  17
i   dd  23
j   we  27
k   rt  12
l   yt  13
m   tt  19
```

Comment: Are there any other rules, which you did not mention here?  I am asking because the row `l ah 56` is in file2, while the total of the previous rows + 56 is still below 172, it should have fitted in file1 too?

Comment: @Luuk- There are no other rules, this was just an example which i manually calculated.

Comment: @TrueEntertainer, Request you to kindly do add your efforts which you have put in order to solve this problem(there is nothing wrong or right here, as we all are here for learning) as per Sundeep sir's request. My answer is ready once you add it, will add it then, cheers.

Comment: a=$(awk '{s+=$3}END{print s}' test7.txt) this would calculate the total sum, from c=$(($a / 3)) We can get the value for each node, I tried but not getting logic for the for loop(apologize, i am still learning Bash)

Comment: @TrueEntertainer, Thanks for showing your efforts please do add them in your question as comments are not meant for code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  sum+=$NF
  next
}
FNR==1{
  count=sum/3
}
{
  curr_sum+=$NF
}
(curr_sum>=count || FNR==1) && fileCnt<=2{
  close(out_file)
  out_file="file" ++fileCnt
  curr_sum=$NF
}
{
  print > (out_file)
}'   Input_file  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                               ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                                            ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first time Input_file is being read.
  sum+=$NF                                          ##Taking sum of last field of all lines here and keep adding them to get cumulative sum of whole Input_file.
  next                                              ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
FNR==1{                                             ##Checking condition if its first line for 2nd time reading of Input_file.
  count=sum/3                                       ##Creating count with value of sum/3 here.
}
{
  curr_sum+=$NF                                     ##Keep adding lst field sum in curr_sum here.
}
(curr_sum>=count || FNR==1) && fileCnt<=2{          ##Checking if current sum is <= count OR its first line(in 2nd time reading) AND output file count is <=2 here.
  close(out_file)                                   ##Closing output file here, may NOT be needed here since we are having only 3 files here in output.
  out_file="file" ++fileCnt                         ##Creating output file name here.
  curr_sum=$NF                                      ##Keep adding lst field sum in curr_sum here.
}
{
  print > (out_file)                                ##Printing current line into output file here.
}'   Input_file  Input_file                         ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @RavinderSingh13 That resolved my query.

Comment: @TrueEntertainer, your welcome, keep sharing and keep learning on this great site SO cheers :) One more thing just add your efforts in your question always as its highly encouraged on SO, you could add your efforts from comments to question too(like I mentioned previously in my comments) cheers

Comment: @RavinderSingh13- Can we anyhow have almost equal value in all the 3 files, with the above code as well I could see some differences in the sum of all the 3 files--file1 sum is 163, file2 sum is 153 and file3 sum is 200

Comment: @TrueEntertainer, Sorry I didn't get, output files came as per your shown samples. Could you please lemme know what kind of output files you are looking please?

Comment: Yeah output is coming correct....I just want if value can be distributed somehow equally, at the moment i could see some differences between the first/second and third file sum, for example- file1 sum is 163, file2 sum is 153 and file3 sum is 200

Comment: @TrueEntertainer, In my humble opinion it will be a different question itself and may confuse future users who are referring this thread. I would like to request you to please open a new thread for this question along with your efforts that will be better, cheers and happy learning on this great site cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ L[nr++]=$0; sum+=$3 }
     END{ sumpf=sum/3; sum=0; file=1; 
          for(i in L) { split(L[i],a); 
          if ((sum+a[3])>sumpf && file<3) { file+=1; sum=0; }; 
          print i, L[i] > "file" file;
          sum+=a[3]; 
        }
    }'  input
```

- This script will read all input into array `L`, and calculate `sum`
- Int the END block the sumPerFile is calculated `sumpf`, and the output is done.

In contrast to the other solution, this only needs one inputfile.

Comment: @Luuk- So with the above code if i sum the output of all the three files, File1 sum is coming as 143, file2 sum as 172 and file3 sum as 201, i do see lot of difference between the sum of first and third file can they be adjusted a bit, so that sum of all the three file is almost the same.

Comment: That's why i asked if there are any other rules, and you replied "There are no other rules"!

Comment: @Luuk- for the above query i have raised a another question in addition to it, can you please help-"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62441945/sum-value-of-a-3rd-row-and-divide-rows-in-such-a-way-that-their-sum-values-match"