# sum value of a 3rd row and divide rows in such a way that their sum values matches

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a file as below with n number of rows, I want to total it's sum(based on 3rd column) and distribute rows accordingly in 3 different files(based on sum of each)

For example- if we sum all the 3rd column values it's total is coming as 516 and if we divide it by 3 it is 172.

So i want to add a rows to a file so it doesn't exceed 172 mark, same with the 2nd file and rest all rows should move to the third file.

- Just have to make sure sum value of all the 3 files should match(small difference is fine)

  - may be it should start checking the values from the top and keep on searching till the end and try to add as much it can(just have to make sure total value doesn't exceed the 172 mark(which is one third of the total sum))
  - It should avoid all the rows which has third value as 0 and at last distribute all of them amongst all the 3 files in such a way that their row count should also be somewhere near equal.

This is in addition to question-"[sum value of a 3rd row and divide rows accordingly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62425230/sum-value-of-a-3rd-row-and-divide-rows-accordingly)"

Input file

```
a aa 0
b ab 55
c ac 17
a dy 0
y ae 12
a dl 34
a fk 45
l ah 56
o aj 76 
l ai 19 
q al 0
d pl 64
e ik 0
f ll 0
g dl 25 
h fr 17
i dd 23
j we 27
k rt 25
l yt 0
m tt 19
```

expected output

file1
Total (172)

```
b ab 55
c ac 17
y ae 12
a dl 34
a fk 45
m tt 9
```

file2
Total (168)

```
l ah 56
o aj 76 
l ai 19 
h fr 17
```

file3
Total (174)

```
d pl 64
g dl 25
i dd 23
j we 27
k rt 35
```

Later it should check for all the 0 column and divide it in such a way that total rows of each file can also be balanced a bit.

```
a aa 0
a dy 0
q al 0
e ik 0
f ll 0
l yt 0
```

so the final output would be

file1

```
b ab 55
c ac 17
y ae 12
a dl 34
a fk 45
m tt 9
a aa 0
```

file2

```
l ah 56
o aj 76 
l ai 19 
h fr 17
a dy 0
q al 0
e ik 0
```

file3

```
d pl 64
g dl 25
i dd 23
j we 27
k rt 35
f ll 0
l yt 0
```

OP's attempts from comments:

`awk '{ L[nr++]=$0; sum+=$3 } END{ sumpf=sum/3; sum=0; file=1; for(i in L) { split(L[i],a); if ((sum+a[3])>sumpf && file<3) { file+=1; sum=0; }; print i, L[i] > "file" file; sum+=a[3]; } }' input`

Comment: @TrueEntertainer, Request you to please do add your efforts like you shown last time in your previous post, add them in your question and you will see people helping you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13- I have the logic in mind but not sure of the syntax how it can be achieved as i am starter in linux.


Logic like- it should start checking the values from the top and keep on searching till the end and try to add as much it can(just have to make sure total value doesn't exceed the 172 mark(which is one third of the total sum))

-It should avoid all the rows which has third value as 0 and at last distribute all of them amongst all the 3 files in such a way that their row count should also be somewhere near equal.

Comment: @TrueEntertainer, sure, please add all these mentioned efforts/details in your question, thank you.

Comment: @ravinderSingh13- I tried but not getting the syntax how i can put it in a loop.

Comment: @TrueEntertainer, not knowing something is never an issue, since we all are here to learn, adding efforts in your Question is important what people encourage on SO. whatever you have written in comments above copy/paste it in your question or whatever you have tried(irrespective of its having issues or not, as we all are here to learn), just add it and I will add my answer then cheers :)

Comment: I am trying to add logic to what Lukk mentioned but not getting through-

awk '{ L[nr++]=$0; sum+=$3 }
     END{ sumpf=sum/3; sum=0; file=1; 
          for(i in L) { split(L[i],a); 
          if ((sum+a[3])>sumpf && file<3) { file+=1; sum=0; }; 
          print i, L[i] > "file" file;
          sum+=a[3]; 
        }
    }'  input

Comment: @TrueEntertainer, ok thanks I added your attempt in your solution now, which I was requesting you comments are not meant for codes, its always advisable to add them in your question, lemme add my suggestion now.

Comment: @TrueEntertainer: SO is not meant to write code for you, so you can copy/paste. there are other site which provide course information, where you can learn how to do stuff in, i.e., awk.    A lot of info an awk can be found in the [man-pages](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), i wish you succes with the reading of those!

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: Please let him try to find more himself...... (please?!)

Comment: @Luuk, sure deleted my answer, I didn't know it was your code, sorry for that.

Comment: @Luuk, yeah even I tried my best to ask OP to add the same and I deleted my answer too, totally agree with you, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of scenario's you can follow:

**Scenario 1)**

1. Read values and add them to file1, as long as, total is below required total
2. If Value of file1 is near required total, add values to file2, until a required total
3. If value of file2 is near required total start adding the rest to file3.

This will get you a result like: 
[image]

With totals of respectively for file1, file2 and file 3: 163, 153, 200

This might not satisfy the needs, so,

**Scenario 2)**

1. What is we first order the items descending, and then follow Scenario 1 ?

We end up with: 
[image]

Wow, this is even less satisfying! I will not even count the totals!

Now it's up to the OP [TrueEntertainer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12457460/true-entertainer) to think of another scenario, where the three tables are filled more evenly.

It should really **not** be that hard to find a better way than the above 2 scenario's !!